# TextBox not displaying initial text in sequence of code C#

Tags: c#, textbox

I am trying to figure out why I never see the "AAAA" displayed in textBox1 when I click button1. I only have a button and a textBox on a Form that is it. The cursor goes to WaitCursor fine. If I add a standard message box between the WaitCursor code and For statement I do see the "AAAA"? Why is "AAAA" never seen in Example 1 (below)? Yes I am new to programming so sorry if this is obvious. If I use Breakpoint textBox1.Text does equal "AAAA" but is never shown in Example 1.

```
    //Example 1 without message box:
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "AAAA";
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000001; i++)
        {

        }
        textBox1.Text = "BBBB";
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
    //Example 2 with message box:
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "AAAA";
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000001; i++)
        {

        }
        textBox1.Text = "BBBB";
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

Comment: The button click handler is being executed on the UI thread. The UI will not update until the method exits. When you show the message box, the application is probably processing windows messages and that's why it works in that case.

Comment: The `for` loop is blocking the thread, so the UI never gets around to updating.  It's basically an optimization so the UI doesn't have to repaint after every single change.

Comment: Ah cool. That makes sense. Thank you for those two comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your first code block : you can not see that because `AAAA` will be replaced with `BBBB` immediately after loop.

in your second code block : you can see the `AAAA` untill you confirm the message box.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. Why is it not there before the loop? Again sorry if this is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of for loop use this, make your method `async:`

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "AAAA";
    this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    await Task.Delay(5000); // wait 5 second asynchronously
    textBox1.Text = "BBBB";
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```

Actualy your `AAAA` is displaying in textBox but you can't see it.Because it's happening very quickly.Second example you see AAAA because it's stoping for MessageBox and doesn't going to for loop unless you close your MessageBox.

Comment: Not entirely sure if this would work, but if you still want to use the `for` loop, try adding `Thread.Sleep(10)` inside the loop body and make your loop go to 500, not 1000...01. This would add a 5 second delay, waiting 10mS x 500 times. Might be worth a try...

Comment: Hi, just tried it. It works in terms of creating a delay and the wait cursor, but the AAAA is not seen. Cheers for the suggestion.